# How to prevent adding default table alias in hibernate @Joinformula

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

In my application I am using the following `@JoinFormula`

`@JoinFormula(value="(select s.\"Id\" from \"Student\" s where ash.\"Class_Id\" = id)" )`

However, at runtime the generated query is:

```
(
    select
        s.cla0_."Id"
    from
        cla0_."Student" s
    where
        s.cla0_."Class_Id" = cla0_.id) as formula4_0_,
```

I need to prevent adding `cla0_` table alias to the formula query. How could it be done in hibernate?
I am using it in spring boot, and postgres as database.